# How to read file content using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload

I have file from client that i have to read on server side and send back to client for download , How can i acheive that task using nodejs. I tried with `fs` but i am getting some error.

`console.log(data)` is coming as empty object

server.js

```
   var multiparty = require('multiparty');

var data = new multiparty.Form();
export function create(req, res) {

 data.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
   console.log(files);
    var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(files.file[0].path,'utf8');
     res.json(fileContent   );
    });
}
```

router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./fileUpload.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/fileUpload',controller.create);


module.exports = router;
```

fileData

```
{ file:
   [ { fieldName: 'file',
       originalFilename: 'sco_poc.bpmn',
       path: 'C:\\Users\\9u\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\f4DG8L7nCpNyNvVPYqGPkd44.bpmn',
       headers: [Object],
       size: 11078 } ] }
```

Comment: `some error`?  What exact error are you getting?  Can you show more of the relevant code?  The only error I see could be happening in your code would be if `fs.readFile()` is failing.  If so, then either the filename/path is incorrect, the file doesn't exist or you don't have permissions to read that file.  The exact error code it's providing would tell you which it is.  Also, your `throw err` does nothing useful as that just throws asynchronously into the `fs.readFile()` sub-system where there is no way to handle or catch that error.  So, start by at least logging the error.

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
`

Comment: That sounds like req.files is not what you think it is.

Comment: I understand but my problem is more of how can i read file content ,can `fs` can read multipart file or i need to use other library ?

Comment: as it seems you are using expressjs, you can use the [res.sendFile](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) method to let the user download the file.

Comment: `fs.readFile()` reads file from disk, not files uploaded by the user in a POST.  You aren't disclosing enough code for us to understand what you are actually trying to do here.  For example, are you using `multer` for file upload?  If so, show us how you have multer configured and show us what calls this `create()` function.

Comment: @jfriend00 i have updated my question i am using `multiparty` but here problem is first time it works but second time it does not work becuase of `path` issue `files.file[0].path  TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
`. if we can not use `fs.readFile()` what will be other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying download a local file the path from your JSON object 'fileData'. My example below is written in NodeJS

First, you will need to stringify your JSONobject

```
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify({ file:
   [ { fieldName: 'file',
       originalFilename: 'sco_poc.bpmn',
       path: 'C:\\Users\\9u\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\f4DG8L7nCpNyNvVPYqGPkd44.bpmn',
       headers: [Object],
       size: 11078 } ] });
//console.log(jsonString)//print jsonString contents
```

Second, parse it into a JavaScript object

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
//console.log(jsonObj); //print jsonObj contents
```

Third, get path from jsonObj

```
var path = jsonObj.file[0].path;
```

Finally, read the (local) file

```
fs.readFile(path,function(err,data){
        var fileData="";
        fileData+=data;
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Location': '<if needed>',
            'Content-Type':'<expected content-type>'
        });
        res.end(fileData); //ends response, and sends to client
    });
```

Comment: getting this error `  var path = jsonObj.file[0].path;
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the very first example on the multiparty NPM page here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty, you will see that you need to run this for each new request, not just once that you reuse over and over:

```
var form = new multiparty.Form();
```

So, for starter move that into your request handler.  Then, if you're unsure how to use the results, I'd suggest you add this:

```
console.log(fields, files);
```

And, this should show you what data you actually have.

FYI, you can see errors in the parsing with this:

```
form.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Error parsing form: ' + err.stack);
});
```

Also, note this statement from the documentation:

> If cb is provided, autoFields and autoFiles are set to true and all
>   fields and files are collected and passed to the callback, removing
>   the need to listen to any events on form. This is for convenience when
>   you want to read everything, but be sure to write cleanup code, as
>   this will write all uploaded files to the disk, even ones you may not
>   be interested in.

You will need to cleanup files on disk after each request or they will accumulate.